# Como fazer deploy de uma aplicação vuejs (browserify) no heroku?

Tags: vue.js, heroku, vue.js-2, javascript

Levantei o servidor com `express`, porém usando um esquema para o `webpack` pois não encontrei nada relacionado ao `browserify`, segue o código...

```
// server.js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
app = express();
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + "/dist"));
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port);
console.log('server started '+ port);
```

já está tudo configurado corretamente, mas está aparecendo somente...

> Cannot GET /

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "watchify": "watchify -vd -p browserify-hmr -e src/main.js -o dist/build.js",
    "serve": "http-server -o -s -c 1 -a localhost",
    "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel watchify serve",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production browserify -g envify src/main.js | uglifyjs -c warnings=false -m > dist/build.js",
    "postinstall": "npm install express",
    "start" : "node server.js"
  },
```

Com o comando que está no `start` o servidor levanta, porém a aplicação não é encontrada.

Obs. para iniciá-la localmente é necessário um `npm run dev` que não foi possível executar em `start` no heroku.

Comment: Como está seu `package.json`? O Heroku logs pode ajudar, veja se tem algo estranho nele

Comment: Adicionei a parte relevante do package.json, também tentei verificar os logs, mas não me mostra nada.

Comment: Pode nos mostrar o server.js pf Felipe?

Comment: @LucasCosta, já está na pergunta

Comment: Ah sim, me atentei ao comentário. Experimente deixar o start dessa forma: `"start": "./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js -p --progress && node server.js"`. E verifique se as dependencia do webpack estão no package.json corretamente tb

Comment: Perdão, tinha colocado o package.json errado, já editei, testei a solução acima e não deu certo...

Comment: Oi Felipe, tens esse projeto no github ou podes criar um `.zip` para podermos testar?

Comment: veja se esse tutorial serve https://medium.com/netscape/deploying-a-vue-js-2-x-app-to-heroku-in-5-steps-tutorial-a69845ace489

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está usando o `http-server` como servidor, uma opção é executar `npm-run-all` no *start* e para hospedar no Heroku omitir o host. Com esas alterações o app irá ser interpretado:

```
{
  "name": "teste",
  "description": "primeiro projeto em vue",
  "author": "teste",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "watchify": "watchify -vd -p browserify-hmr -e src/main.js -o dist/build.js",
    "serve": "http-server -o -s -c 1 -a",
    "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel watchify serve",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production browserify -g envify src/main.js | uglifyjs -c warnings=false -m > dist/build.js",
    "postinstall": "npm install express",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel watchify serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "vue": "^2.0.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.0",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "browserify": "^13.0.1",
    "browserify-hmr": "^0.3.1",
    "cross-env": "^1.0.6",
    "envify": "^3.4.1",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^2.1.2",
    "uglify-js": "^2.5.0",
    "vueify": "^9.1.0",
    "watchify": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "vueify",
      "babelify"
    ]
  },
  "browser": {
    "vue": "vue/dist/vue.common.js"
  }
}
```

Deixei como *dependencies* e não *devDependencies* para que o Heroku possa usá-los, e alterei as propriedades `start` e `serve`.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, muito obrigado!